# What happens when there's a zero?

Tags: geometry

So basically I have a linear equation that I have to find the $x$ and $y$ intercepts for, to graph. I have $3y+x=3$. Would I replace the $x$ to a $1$ when I solve for it? Any links leading somewhere or help would be great.

Comment: Start with $x=0$ then $y=0$ to find two points to connect...

Comment: So, `3y+0=3` then divide `3y` from `3`? And then do the inverse for the `y`?

Comment: solve for $y$ to get $y=\frac{1}{3}(3-x)$ to plot

Comment: ploting [http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%283-x%29%2F3]

Comment: @janmarqz Where'd you get the _(3-x)_?

Comment: $3y+x=3$ ---> $3y=3-x$ ---> $y=\frac{1}{3}(3-x)$

Comment: So i'd move the x to the right? Then divide? Also thanks for the help so far @janmarqz

Comment: see my answer please

Answer (score 2):

You need to find the $x$ and $y$ intercepts. First, let's find the $x$ intercept. That is when the line passes through the $x$-axis. But that happens when $y=0$ (you can see that from the graph). So that means we have
$$
3(0)+x=x=3
$$
So the $x$ intercept when $x=3$ and is $(3,0)$! Now we look for the $y$-intercept. That happens when the line passes through the $y$-axis. But that happens when $x=0$ (again, you can see this from the graph), so we have
$$
3y+0=3y=3\rightarrow y=1
$$
So the $y$-intercept is when $y=1$, so it is $(0,1)$. This function (the line) is zero when it intercepts the $x$-axis, which we have already found.

Comment: Thanks for such a great post. When you did `3(0)+x=x=3`, is there a formula I should be following? Perhaps standard form? @mathematics2x2life

Comment: @Sally: "standard form" has a couple different translations: $ax+by=c, y=mx+b, x=ny+b$ and so on.  "$y=mx+b$" is often called "point-slope" form while "$ax+by=c$" is sometimes called "standard form"...

Comment: I'm sorry if i'm making this harder then it should be, but the formula would be "point-slope"? I just want to learn this correctly since everyone i've been though is really bad at teaching it. @abiessu

Comment: Point slope typically refers to something of this form, $y-y_0=m(x-x_0)$, where $m$ is the slope you are given and and $(x_0,y_0)$ is the point you are given. And as for your original question. The formula I used was the one you gave $3y+x$. If $y=0$, then we have $3y+x=3(0)+x=0+x=x$. But we also know that $3y+x=3$. Since the left side is $x$ when $y=0$, we know that $x=3$.

Answer (score 0):

Deduce like this: $$3y+x=3,$$ ---> $$x=3-3y.$$ 
Then you can see  that at $y=1$ you have $x=0$.

Comment: this is the other alternative: Solve for $x$ and evaluate at $y=1$

Comment: my apologies for the created above confusion

Comment: I really thank you for all the help. I still can't understand it. I know it probably really simple but i'm making it harder. So move the X all by its self. Then minus the `3` for the `3y`?

Comment: I figured it out. I thank you for the help.

Comment: move the 3y to the right so you x=3-3y